# Laravel Approved Categories get in same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Laravel version: 7.0

This is my `categories` table.

```
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->default(0);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

There are two levels of categories.
If `parent_id` is `0`, then that is `category`, if `parent_id` isn't `0`, then that is `subcategory`.

I want to get all `categories & subcategories` which have `status == 1` & if it's `subcategory`, then its `parent category's status` should be `1`.

I made `Category` model.

```
$categories = Category::where('status', 1)->get();
```

Above query could get subcategories which the `parent category's status == 0`.
How can I filter all categories & subcategories?
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the task into two.

1. Get all categories (status = 1 and parent_id = 0)
2. Get all subcategories (status = 1 and parent_id != 0 and parent.status = 1)

```php
$categories = Category::query()
    // 1.
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereStatus(1)->whereParentId(0);
    })
    // 2.
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query
            ->where('parent_id', '!=', 0)
            ->whereStatus(1)
            ->whereHas('parent', function ($query) {
                $query->whereStatus(1);
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

Remember that PHP closures works as `( )` in SQL. So the above reads as:

```
(parent_id = 0 AND status = 1) 
    OR 
(parent_id != 0 AND status = 1 AND (sub query that does a count > 0))
```

They are needed since we are using the `orWhere`.

The part you were missing were probably the `whereHas`. That lets you query a relation. In my example above I assume the inverse `belongsTo` relationship is set up on your `Category` model as `parent()`.

Comment: Great, Works like charm!
Thanks, `orWhere(function $query)` here, shouldn't we put `($query)` ?